# .NET Core Angular client SPA has issue redirecting on logout to IdentityServer4 IDP

Tags: .net-core, cors, identityserver4, openid-connect

I've an Angular Client which needs to be authentcated. This client is hosted in .NetCore SPA. Now using IdentityServer4, I've setup the IDP to authenticate the Client.

Everything works fine for login. Here the client automatically redirects to IDP project to login. Once credentials are entered it will redirect back to the client app.

However, for logout it's not working. On the Angular client which is hosted as a SPA in .netcore, I've a logout button. This logout button event will call the API controller in the same client. In this controller there is code to Signout from the httpContext.

My expectation was, when the logout action is called in the controller it will logout and redirect me back to the IDP. On a positive note, I've implemented the same in MVC client(no SPA and angular) and it works for the logout by redirecting me back to the IDP.

Also another positive, on the angular client on logout it actually tries to logout, but the **CORS policy is blocking it**. The error message in the browser console has the redirect url as part of the error message. This url works when i click on it by redirecting me to the IDP and logging me out.

**I'm not able to figure out what CORS policy I have to add to make this redirect work. I've tried adding CORS to the startup class, but did not work. Help please**

**Browser error message:**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44336/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44374%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlMwbFpqUi1QazItS0dLc2xxaFlQQ2ciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.bd35dk-lcolUxgoNAzzc4kKIORQIsmeSu5JaARpyqj1I6cv5P6LSHrcdw3YmZ80q_tF8WLi7ywIml-enEP4JAe-nbYw7gSlFt9qHtw5eSF37dMdBZq7UUXt6EoK29xs9lp6TyIB11pzgRZ8tPVAPw0Y8rNpGSGYtjfWjp7t4FdKthvUchAo_SNh6l40S5oV0Yo_YIWfHtjxM-nLZXia0YCvjNEQChmTmkzSMCIdGnVqawhIzQ_O7jv0c1T7kCwaF5YGyer3ZUyj1UM53JTBbbGpKDrDh2DV-kd4tvhoaLnWQAoUqCQ1Ofl_kHc8vffqE7RRPGmQLQYOM48186hIe0g&state=CfDJ8DRPXADjz9hKioMAFvg6DCP1P37ODZ4R81EV3uFXBpxiOLWoJY6GDEcbYNZzB--zZjv-Z94PSfMJkcoJhQcmHAvmM_9yKL9hPaGqmucpJrO_wv74Fj8bmdm8C7l_MJZ3VaNahF5Bqvi9tWFUikbr-HJ_uI0GiGX6qsj5mkrp8K4x&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44374/api/Authorization/Logout') from origin 'https://localhost:44374' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

**And the API controller logout code:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var httpclient = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await httpclient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44336/");

        // get the access token to revoke 
        var accessToken = await HttpContext
          .GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        {
            var revokeAccessTokenResponse =
                await httpclient.RevokeTokenAsync(new TokenRevocationRequest
                {
                    Address = disco.RevocationEndpoint,
                    ClientId = "App_ClientId",
                    ClientSecret = "someSecret",

                    Token = accessToken
                });

            if (revokeAccessTokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception("Problem encountered while revoking the access token."
                    , revokeAccessTokenResponse.Exception);
            }
        }

        // Clears the  local cookie ("Cookies" must match name from scheme)
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    }
```

**Startup.cs with entire client configuration**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<ActivityTrackerAPIHttpClient>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        }).AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServer:Authority"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["IdentityServer:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["IdentityServer:ClientSecret"];
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");
            options.Scope.Add(Configuration["IdentityServer:ApiName"]);
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
            options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
            options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            };
        });

        services.ConfigureLoggerService();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync("oidc");
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you go to your api to revoke the token and not directly to the idp from your client? If you are using the oidc.js you can just use the this.mgr.signoutRedirect() from your client

Comment: I am using **Hybrid Flow** and not **Implicit Flow**. So my angular Client know nothing about the authorization. Authorization is setup on the .Net core MVC angular SPA which hosts the Angular. Redirection to IPD works when I am Logging in. However for logout, redirection to IDP is blocked by CORS. I've updated the code above to reflect how login redirection is implemented, which is slightly different to logout.

Comment: Please post `Client` configuration

Comment: Pablo, I've update the question with the entire client configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry @JoeIpe I'm talking about Client configuration on IdentityServer

Comment: @Joelpe Did you already find a solution? I'm facing the exact same issue...

Comment: Pieter, I've posted my solution as an answer. This is an ugly solution I came up out of desperation. 
Better solution is to implement client security in the angular side. "oidc-client" package can be used to leverage the openID & OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a temporary solution at that point. However I realized, it is ideal to do the client security in the angular side.

My temp solution below.

**Startup.cs of client**

```
options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
                        {
                            var protocolMessage = context.ProtocolMessage;
                            var param = "";
                            foreach (var parameter in protocolMessage.Parameters)
                            {
                                param += $"{parameter.Key}={parameter.Value}$";
                            }
                            var url = $"{protocolMessage.IssuerAddress}?{param}x-client-SKU={protocolMessage.SkuTelemetryValue}&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0";

                            context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("LogoutUrl", url);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
```

Also enable session in the client startup.cs by adding `services.AddSession();` in ConfigureServices method and then add `app.UseSession();` in the Configure method.

**In the controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var url = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LogoutUrl");

        return Ok(url);
    }
```